# How to handle the state of multiple checkboxes in child component by the parent in react?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-props, react-component, conditional-rendering

I have multiple check-boxes which are dynamic. These check boxes are placed (assume) in "B" component.
I have managed the state of these check boxes in "A" component which is the parent of "B".
***When one or all the check boxes are clicked I want to render a div***

***expected result*** : render div if one or all the check boxes are clicked. If none is selected the div should be hidden. Basically the div should be visible even if a single checkbox is checked.

***current result*** : When one check box is clicked the div gets rendered but if another checkbox is selected the div disappears.

Here's my A component (Parent)

```
const A = () => {
   const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false) // state that holds state of check boxes 

   return (
      {isChecked ? <div>Some Content..</div> : null} // rendering the div according to the state of the checkboxes

      <Child isChecked={isChecked} setIsChecked={setIsChecked} />
  ) 
}
```

Code of Child Component

```
 const Child = props => {
      
        return (
           {checkBoxList.map((box, index) => (
              <CustomCheckBox
                 key={index}
                 name={`check-box-${index}`}  // to uniquely identify each check box 
                 isChecked={props.isChecked}
                 setIsChecked={props.setIsChecked} />
           ))}
        )
    }
```

CustomCheckBox component :

```
 const CustomCheckBox = props => {
    
      const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
         props.isChecked ? props.setIsChecked(false) : props.setIsChecked(true)
      }
    
      return <input name={props.name} type="checkBox" onChange={onChangeHandler} />;
 };
    
  CustomCheckBox.propTypes = {
    name: string
  }
```

I'm aware that the parent component state is only capable of handling a single check box right now.

The reason for the current result is because of the condition that I have included in `onChangeHandler` function.

```
  props.isChecked ? props.setIsChecked(false) : props.setIsChecked(true)
```

I'm confused about how to handle the state of multiple check boxes in the above stated scenario using a single handler function !

Answer (score 0):

you can keep track of checkbox indexes that you click instead of if it was clicked

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([]) // state that holds state of checked boxes
```

then handler would become:

```
const onChangeHandler = (index) => {

    const result = props.isChecked;
    var i = result.indexOf(index);
    if (i> -1) {
        result.splice(i, 1);
    }
    else {
        result = [...result, index]
    }
    props.setIsChecked(result)
  }
```

so in the parent you would check if isChecked.length> 0

Hope this helps